# onLayout not called in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to detect the width change with this code

```
class MyClass extends Component {
  onLayout(event) {
    const {x, y, height, width} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    const newHeight = this.state.view2LayoutProps.height + 1;
    const newLayout = {
        height: newHeight ,
        width: width,
        left: x,
        top: y,
      };

    this.setState({ view2LayoutProps: newLayout });
    alert('ok');
  }
```

the the `onLayout` function is never called. Is something wrong with the code? I found the code in this website.

Comment: You forgot to put the link to the website you found the code at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you ever add `onLayout` to a component that `MyClass` renders? It's not a lifecycle method on the `React.Component` instance (like `componentDidMount`), it's an event *from another component* that you can capture by providing an `onLayout`  *callback* property to the other component. It's a feature of the `react-native` builtin components.

```
class MyClass extends Component {
  onLayout(event) {
    const {x, y, height, width} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    const newHeight = this.state.view2LayoutProps.height + 1;
    const newLayout = {
        height: newHeight ,
        width: width,
        left: x,
        top: y,
      };

    this.setState({ view2LayoutProps: newLayout });
    alert('ok');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View onLayout={e => this.onLayout(e)} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool explanation. This onLayout is never called https://github.com/reactrondev/react-native-web-swiper/blob/master/src/Swiper.js#L242 on Safari mobile iOS <= 12, do you have a clue why ? It seems that react-native-web is having a bug .